# Converting SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle

In my project, I have a database in SQL which was working fine. But now I have to make the application support oracle db too.

Some limitations I found out was that in Oracle, there is no bit field and the table name cannot be greater than 30 char. Is there any other limitation that I need to keep in mind.

Any suggestion from past experience will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly from my earlier Oracle days:

- there's no `IDENTITY` column specification in Oracle (you need to use sequences instead)
- you cannot simply return a `SELECT (columns)` from a stored procedure (you need to use `REF CURSOR`)
- of course, all stored procs/funcs are different (Oracle's PL/SQL is not the same as T-SQL)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL `ISNULL` counterpart in Oracle is `NVL`

```
select ISNULL(col, 0)...

select NVL(col, 0)...
```

You will also struggle if you attempt to select without a `from` in Oracle. Use `dual`:

```
select 'Hello' from DUAL
```

Bear in mind also, that in Oracle there is the distinction between PL/SQL (Procedural SQL) and pure SQL. They are two distinct and separate languages, that are commonly combined.

Comment: What is the counter part of CTE, Case ?

Comment: CTE is called Subquery Factoring http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Answer (score 2):

- Varchar in Oracle Databases called
  varchar2 is limited to 4000
  characters
- Oracles concept of temporary tables is different, they have a global redefined structure
- by default sort order and string compare is case-sensitive

When you add a column to a select *

```
Select * from table_1 order by id;
```

you must prefix the ***** by the table_name or an alias

```
Select 
   (row_number() over (order by id)) rn,  
   t.* 
from table_1 t
order by id;
```

Oracle doesn't distinguish between null and '' (empty string). For insert and update you ca use '', but to query you must use null

```
create table t1 (
    id NUMBER(10),  
    val varchar2(20)
);

Insert into t1 values (1, '');
Insert into t1 values (2, null);
Select * from t1 where stringval = 0; -- correct but empty
Select * from t1 where stringval is null; -- returns both rows
```

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE do not support **TOP** clause. Instead of **TOP** you can use **ROWNUM**.

**SQL Server:** [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM CUSTOMERS
```

**ORACLE:** [ROWNUM Pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm#sthref831)

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```